# How to zoom map programmatically Openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

I want to draw a square around a marker. if I draw a large square the map should zoom out automatically so that we can see the square completely. If I draw a small square the map should zoom in automatically to show the square completely.

[In this image I have drawn small square so we can see the square completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SapoL.jpg)

[In this image I have drawn a larger square, Since the map is not zooming out we cannot see the square sides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac85p.jpg)

Answer (score 18):

See [ol.View](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.View.html) in the openlayers 3 documentation. There is a function `setZoom(zoom)`.

So if your map variable is `map`, to zoom in use `map.getView().setZoom(map.getView().getZoom() + 1);` and to zoom out use `map.getView().setZoom(map.getView().getZoom() - 1);`

Answer (score 5):

If you want a smooth zoom:

```
map.getView().animate({
  zoom: map.getView().getZoom() + 1,
  duration: 250
})
```